# how to install wordpress into wordpress new directory for development cpanel

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a directory into wordpress and upload the Wordpress files.I have created a database and set username and password.
when I installed the Wordpress and enter the db name user and pass and the error comes error to establish to connecting with database.

[directory image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tCzC.png)

Comment: if you have any video link which show complete method so please send

Answer (score 0):

follow the below video & complete the steps. hopefully, work it.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=inokGZeemUw